# Getting the data out of an Array in PHP $_Post

Tags: php

Suppose I send an array of emails.  The emails is an array containing john@test.com, tom@test.com, jerry@test.com....etc

From the receiving side I am trying retrieve the emails.

```
   foreach ($_POST['emails'] as $i => $value) {
    echo "emails[$i] is $value<br />";
    }
```

Is this the correct way to do it?
for the foreach loop, would it iterate until all the data out of emails array finished?

Comment: You probably could've tried this in less time than it took to post the question...

Comment: I trying to send in through mobile device from the front and PHP at back.If it's not working hopefully some right pointers to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. You can probably use a more simple loop though:

```
foreach ($_POST['emails'] as $email) {
    echo $email, "<br>";
}
```

Be sure to [sanitize your inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php) !

---

If you're calling an email-sending function or something, you can use [array_walk()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php).

```
function send_mail($email){
    echo "Sending email to {$email}";
}

array_walk($_POST['emails'], 'send_mail');

# Sending email to john@test.com
# Sending email to tom@test.com
# Sending email to jerry@test.com
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
foreach ( $_POST ['emails'] as $value ) {
    echo $value , "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use $value:

```
foreach($_POST['emails'] as $value) {
    echo "Email: {$value}\n";
}
```

Or you can also use the array key to access the value, but there's no point if you don't want to edit values:

```
foreach($_POST['emails'] as $key => $value) {
    echo "Email: " . $_POST['emails'][$key];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No, you use that syntax for associative arrays, `$_POST['emails']` is most likely, not an associative array. The correct way would be something like this instead:

```
foreach ($_POST['emails'] as $email) {
echo "Email: $email<br />";
}
```